# ZeroClipboard Implementation

Tags: javascript, copy, html-table, clipboard, zeroclipboard

I'm using JavaScript to analyze data locally. I'm trying to implement ZeroClipboard to copy  a fairly large HTML table to the clipboard. I got the sample code to work in the following [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xited/25eg20ff/1/). I can also run this code successfully from a web server. The problem I'm having, however, is that this exact code won't work locally in the browser, which is where it will be used. Why will it not work locally, and how can I get it to work? OR Is there another way to copy a huge HTML table to the clipboard? Looking for a front-end solution.

Below is the code:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <button id="copy-button" data-clipboard-text="Copy Me!" title="Click to copy me.">Copy to Clipboard</button>
        <script src="http://zeroclipboard.org/javascripts/zc/v2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
            var client = new ZeroClipboard( document.getElementById("copy-button") );

            client.on( "ready", function( readyEvent ) {
              alert( "ZeroClipboard SWF is ready!" );

                  client.on( "aftercopy", function( event ) {
                        // `this` === `client`
                        // `event.target` === the element that was clicked
                        event.target.style.display = "none";
                        alert("Copied text to clipboard: " + event.data["text/plain"] );
                  });
                });
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the http: from the script src so it reads `<script src="//zeroclipboard.org/javascripts/zc/v2.1.6/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>`

also where is your swf file on local? This might be the problem - remember it is meant to be in the same folder as the HTML or otherwise declared